# Curly braces autoformat whitespace issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I've noticed a weird behavior with visual studio and the auto format of curly braces.

If I type something likes this

```
if(x == 10)
```

and then open a new curly brace, it will look like this: `if(x == 10) { }`
The cursor will be in between both braces. I can hit enter and it automatically converts the code to

```
if(x == 0) {
    // ..
}
```

So that works fine too. My issue is the missing space between the `if` and the `(`. It's missing and should look like this

```
if (x == 0)
```

The weird thing is that - after removing the last curly brace and adding it again, the whitespace will be added. But it doesn't happen initially.
Am I missing a setting?

---

**edit:** I've noticed that it doesn't happen if I call a function, e.g

```
if(x.Equals(..)){ }
```

will result int

```
if (x.Equals(..)) {

}
```

which is correct.

Operators don't seem to work however.

Comment: I've noticed that VS2019 autoformat seems to have lots of little quirks like this.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the settings?`Tools-->Options-->Import and Export settings-->Reset settings`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Below Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > CodeStyle > Formatting there's an option called 'Insert space after keywords in control flow statements'

The code example looks this if the checkbox is...

... unchecked

```
 for(int i; i < x; i++)
```

... checked

```
for (int i; i < x; i++)
```

Comment: I've already checked that option. Weirdly that doesn't happen if I put a function call in the if statement.

Comment: Please hit Ctrl+K+D once and tell us if the autoformat works if manually triggered

Comment: It does work if triggered manually, either through Ctrl+K+D or removing and adding the last curly brace again.

Comment: Below Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>CodeStyle>Formatting>General you can select when the autoformatting should be executed. For me all checkboxes are checked. I don't know what options are available in VS2019, but maybe there's a solution to your problem. Otherwise I'm afraid that I can't help any further.